# Windows 8 does not hibernate without boot menu installed

Tags: windows-8, multi-boot, hibernate, hybrid-boot

I run a quad-boot with Fedora, Ubuntu, ChromiumOS, and Windows 8.  I have discovered that Windows 8 will no longer hibernate - it just brings me back to the lock screen.  When I run it from command-line, I get this:
[image: The requested system device cannot be found.(15299)]

The problem is, Windows also can't do it's fast-startup thing because that involves kernel hibernation.  The only way I can shutdown is with `shutdown /s /t 0` or a shortcut that invokes it.

Apparently, this problem is tied to Windows having its boot manager in control.  That's great, but if I hibernate Windows, its boot manager won't let me start up anything else, defeating the whole point of a multiboot.  Using GRUB, you can hibernate an OS and start up another, then come back to the other one.

How can I keep my multiboot and also be able to hibernate Windows 8?

Comment: Try doing [sfc /scannow](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html).

Comment: Try running (From an elevated command prompt) <code>powercfg -h on</code> to (re)enable hybernation. Does that return any error?

Comment: @K.A It returns no error, but doesn't work.  Even running `powercfg -h off` followed by `powercfg -h on` doesn't work.

Comment: (Also <code> doesn't work in comments, use backticks instead.)

Comment: @harrymc Looks like `sfc` found something, I ran with `/verifyonly` first.  Will reboot and see if it hibernates again.

Comment: After scanning and rebooting, it looks like the issue was unrelated.  Computer doesn't hibernate.

Comment: It's not very good that sfc has found anything at all - I would also do some extensive antivirus scans by well-known products. Also please post the result of [powercfg -energy](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7638/use-powercfg-in-windows-7-to-evaluate-power-efficiency/).

Comment: @WindowsEscapist The error code 15299 typically indicates a corrupted registry. You could try a registry cleaner, or, reinstall the W8

Comment: @DaveRook Is this from Microsoft or experience?  I really don't think there's a corrupted registry - I've been pretty careful with this box.

Comment: @WindowsEscapist Experience and research but in this case, 80% research! It may not matter how careful you are or are not, some times things just go wrong (this *is* my experience). If you have no other options, it may be worth while trying this but it's of course relative as to how desperate you are!

Comment: @DaveRook I mean I am careful to avoid unclean shutdowns or filesystem corruption in general.  Pardon my ignorance, but how would hibernation utilize the registry?  (On a side note, I am reluctant to download and install a registry cleaner; they're not typically very trustworthy.)

Comment: I think you can do a Google search for *site:www.superuser.com ccleaner* and see how many people recommend it. Anyway, to answer your question, I don't know (hence why a comment) but, if there are no other options then I would try.

Comment: I suppose I'll end up trying CCleaner if nothing else works (I've used it before for the janitor function; I just don't think registry cleaners are particularly effective or safe).

Comment: @WindowsEscapist what happen when you try to hibernate through GUI/Powermenu?

Comment: @avirk As per my question, it just goes to the lock screen.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't know what the rules are here for linking to another forum, but given the amount of time this question has been open, I am going to do so and hope you get this resolved.

Take a look at this thread over on the Microsoft Community Forums -

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/hibernate-on-windows-7-with-dual-boot/030ba6d6-d6a2-4d76-875e-78a1fe7b929d

If you go to Page 2 of the replies, there is a response from **captainu replied on 
February 1, 2010** that details a possible workaround for you.

Then on Page 3 of the replies, there is a response from **skariks replied on 
September 16, 2010** that details a more complex possible solution.

I hope this helps you out!

Comment: Lining is fine, but you should usually try to contain the key points in your answer.  This will make sure your answer isn't worthless if the site you linked to goes down.

Comment: Answer 1: Looks like this won't work - the EasyBCD solution requires Windows to be the only operating system capable of hibernating, which defeats a big whole point of my multiboot. Answer 2: The partition is marked as active, so I still don't know what's going on here.